# How to convert PHP's crc32 hash into the MySQL equivalent?

Tags: php, sql, hash

Apparently MySQL's CRC32() function returns an unsigned BIGINT, while PHP returns hexadecimal value.

In PHP:

`hash('crc32','hello world') == 7813f744`

In MySQL:

`SELECT CRC32('hello world') == 222957957`

The PHP CRC32 value is stored in a CHAR(8) column.

I can't figure out how to turn the PHP generated hash into the same value that MySQL produces *only using SQL*. The obvious doesn't seem to work:

`SELECT HEX(CRC32('hello world')) == D4A1185`

`SELECT CONV('7813f744',16,10) == 2014574404`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you may need to use `hash('crc32b', ...)`. Check the first comment here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#107920

Comment: Like i said, i'd like to do this in SQL without having to do anything in PHP, since my may concern is converting the existing data.

Comment: I actually think I misunderstood your question. I thought you were getting different hashes from MySQL and PHP. Let me look up few things ...

Comment: OK. The two hashes are calculated differently. MySQL's `CRC32` uses crc32b polynomial to generate the hash, while PHP's `hash('crc32' ..` uses crc32, which is a different polynomial, producing a completely different hash. I couldn't find any way of generating crc32 (not b) in MySQL. So your only feasable option (as far as I know) is to change the PHP side.

Comment: I see. :( Make that an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 64-bit platform you can safely use [crc32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) function in PHP and `CRC32` in MySQL. Quick test:

```
  php > echo crc32('foobar') . "\n";
  2666930069
```

MySQL:

```
  >select crc32('foobar');
  +-----------------+
  | crc32('foobar') |
  +-----------------+
  |      2666930069 |
  +-----------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is how to convert php crc32 in mysql equivalent (programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the wrapper function that returns the same value as in mysql:

```
function mysql_compatible_crc32($s) {
    $r = crc32($s);
    if($r<0) {
        return 4294967296+$r;
    }
    return $r;
}
```