# mysql update table set field equal php function

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to update a field of a table with the value coming from php built-in function?

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = hash("ripemd256", field2)
```

Comment: What does the function return? Is the same datatype as the column? then it shouldnt be a problem

Comment: Well thats a valid SQL query, but it always good check whether the function returned a valid value.

Comment: hash("ripemd256", field2) is a php built-in function that converts a string into different characters. Basically it is use for password protection.

Comment: @avisheks, the code above creates error. hash("ripemd256", field2) is not recognized by mysql

Comment: I think the length of the result is always the same. Just fit the `field1` to the output. Dont forget to use a WHERE clause also, otherwise you set all field1 to the same value

Comment: you have to make sure that the function runs with the php code so the MySQL syntax is created properly. If you execute that in mysql he will try to find the php function hash but it doesnt exists of course.

Comment: wait a minute, you should run this from php code as its a php code inside mysql_query, or if you want to execute the query directly on mysql client user MySQL equivalent function for hash. Hope that make sense to you...:) ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086316/how-to-convert-phps-crc32-hash-into-the-mysql-equivalent